# When I use a famous figure (Mother Theresa) to represent a larger concept (community).

Tags: phrase-requests

Or what might the iconic figure be called

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You Could Try:

[*Symbolism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/symbolism):

> the use of symbols to express or represent ideas or qualities in literature, art, etc.
>
> Ex. The story was filled with religious symbolism.

Or You Could Try:

[*Metonymy*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metonymy):

> a figure of speech consisting of the use of the name of one thing for that of another of which it is an attribute or with which it is associated (as “crown” in “lands belonging to the crown”)
>
> Ex. The name, arising from this unusual sound, has been by metonymy translated into " God's Voice."